# What is the period called when you first buy a car and you have to go slower?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

What's the period called when you first buy a car and you have to go slower than usual to get the engine working properly in the future?

Can it be used in another meaning?
Because in my language you can use the same word to define a period where you have to pay particular attention to something (in this case, pay attention to the speed of the car).

Comment: https://www.wordreference.com/iten/rodaggio Word Reference is *imbattibile*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you buy a new car, you're supposed to:

- drive at a variety of different speeds
- avoid hard acceleration
- avoid long drives at the same speed (such as on the highway)

In American English, this is called the **break-in** period for the car, or more specifically for the car engine. This term is commonly used for machinery. The **break-in** period is the time in which you are **breaking in** the engine.

The term is also used for clothing, particularly leather clothing which can be very stiff until it is worn for a long time.

Note that the term is meant to evoke a physical process acting on a physical object. It does not specifically imply that the user needs to pay greater attention or act with more care during the break-in period.

As per the comments: In British English, this is called the **run-in** period for the car, the time in which you are **running in** the engine. The phrase "breaking in" is reserved for animals (such as horses).

Comment: *Breaking in* is an American term for British *running in*. In Britain, *breaking in* might be understood to apply to a horse but never to a car or a car engine.

Comment: @Anton I clarified that this phrase is an Americanism.

Comment: Soo, in what case you guys suggest to use *Breaking in* instead of *running in* ? The difference is just that one is in Brithis English and one is in American English?

Comment: _Running in_ is the British expression, _breaking in_ is American, as Anton says.

Comment: *[Break-in (mechanical run-in)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break-in_(mechanical_run-in))* (Wikipedia)

Comment: One additional point - "breaking in" in the UK  is very likely to be confused with burglary ;) Most people don't train horses or know anyone who does. People are very familiar with the idea that if someone breaks in, it's probably to steal your car radio.

Comment: thanks ! @gonefishin'again. xD

Answer (score 8):

It’s called **breaking in** the engine:

> What do we mean by ‘break in’? It comes down to giving the engine time to adjust and operate evenly after rolling off the production line, so no parts are put under excess strain early on. — [6 Ways to Break in a New Car Engine](https://www.holtsauto.com/redex/news/6-ways-to-break-in-a-new-car-engine/)

This definition is also listed in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/break-sth-in), with the British English equivalent being “run something in”:

> If you break in a vehicle, you use it carefully and slowly for a short time when it is new, so that you do not damage its engine.

See also Wikipedia: [Break-in (mechanical run-in)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break-in_(mechanical_run-in))

Comment: I have only ever heard _run in_ in the UK. e use _break in_ for shoes and horses.

Comment: Yes. "Breaking in" is a purely North American usage. Always "running in" for British motor vehicles. When I was a kid people used to put "Running in - please pass" notices in their rear window. With modern engines you don;t have to do this so much.

Comment: AU commentator here:  We'd understand 'running in', but would be more likely to use 'breaking in' - just like with shoes and a range of similar items, eg:computers for the period between bringing home the machine full of factory settings to when you have set up desktop backgrounds, shortcuts, etc.  Breaking in of horses is a slightly different concept, methinks - actually breaking their spirit, rather than wearing it down.

Comment: @mcalex In the UK (and I think also the US) you don’t break _in_ horses, you just break them.

Comment: @MikeScott "you just break them" HAHAHAHAH. Soo I hope you guys don't "break in" horses xD

Comment: @MikeScott - UK site: "As a rough guide it normally takes 3 – 4 weeks to have the horse broken to saddle".

Comment: @Liiuc UK usage is "Running in" for a car, "breaking" for a horse. "Break in" is burglary. Sorry if you don't like it.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Got it ! Thanks